# Resizing preset calendar size

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, size

I want to make a calendar, with a view of only a month in c# winforms of size bigger than the preset one. The control I use is MonthCalendar.

If i change the size in properties or resize with the mouse, the calendar extends in time (for example shows 3 months instead of 1) but does not get bigger, same fontsize, etc...

I tried to change font size but nothing happens.

**How can i resize it scaling fonts and showing the same, but bigger scale?**

Comment: can't this simple thing be done?

Comment: I'm thinking of making a user control with the calendar filling it as dock mode, then scaling it... can this be done? will work scaling only an user control inside a form without scaling the rest of the form?